# HTML in Netbeans image not showing in browser

Tags: html, css, image, netbeans

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.container{
    background-color:#999999;
    width:100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.wrapper{
    margin-top: 50px;
    width:900px;
    margin:auto;
}
.dark{
    background-color: #FF4500;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
#top_div{
    line-height: 40px;
}
#div2{
    height: 220px;
}
```

Above mentioned is my css file

```html
 <html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>My static web Page</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css1.css"/>
    </head> 
    <body>
        
        <div class="container">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div>
                    <img src="img.png"  width="400" height="400" ></img>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="dark">
            <div class="wrapper" id="top_div">
                <h2>The Origin</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="container">
            <div class="wrapper" id="top_div">
This is my styled paragraph
            </div>
        </div> 
        
    </body>
</html>
```

It shows just the image icon and no image is seen on browser.
I have pasted the image in a folder inside the project directory. What is the correct way to add an image, please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure you have the right path  (eg: relative  ./your_file.png

```
<div>
     <img src="./img.png"  width="400" height="400" ></img>>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
<img src="./foldername/imagename.png" width="400" height="400" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below line of code means, your image file `img.png` resides in same folder where you kept `html` file.

```
<img src="img.png"  width="400" height="400" ></img>
```

If it is kept in other folder then, you can provide the related path something like

```
src="../foldername/img.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to clear the temp files from %temp% command, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

If you have two different folders for your HTML files and images then update your img tag as below:

`<img src="../images/img.png"  width="400" height="400" ></img>`

where"images" is the name of the folder where your images are placed.